# Adjust content scale and offset on resize of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have UI which hast two states of layouts (besides portrait-landscape). In each state some other part of UI is exposed (is larger).

Problem is that `UIScrollView` with some `UIImageView` is resized on those states changes, and in each state different part of image is shown since scale and offset remains unchanged.

Is there some nice way to update this scale and offset values so more or less same part of image is shown for a large and small sized `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the UIScrollView method

```
- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Rect is a rectangle in the coordinate space of the view returned by viewForZoomingInScrollView:.

- Determine what rectangle of the zoomed view is being shown.
- Change your views so that the UIScrollView bounds are changed.
- Do the zoomToRect to show the same content, scaled as necessary.

Without having compiled and run this, it should be approximately...

```
CGSize rectSize;
rectSize.origin = scrollview.contentOffset;
rectSize.width = scrollview.bounds.size.width * scrollview.zoomScale;
rectSize.height = scrollview.bounds.size.height * scrollview.zoomScale;

// Do whatever makes the views change

[scrollView zoomToRect:rectSize animated:whateverYouLike];
```

Comment: this should work, question is where should put this? Override `setFrame` or should I do it in `layoutSubviews` or something else. I will try both. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing how you do everything I can't really say.  But... You need to grab the existing rectangle info before you change the UI and update the scrollview immediately after you change the UI.

Comment: OK I had to fight with other functionality of my scroll view (fix some bug) and in mean time UI spec has been changed. So I'm accepting answer since it should work (I didn't verify it).